# Traefik with Docker on OSX - Gateway Timeout following official instructions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

- OSX 10.11.6
- Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

Following these instructions: https://docs.traefik.io/#test-it

I start with default networks:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
dc218a8c3b42        bridge              bridge              local
061dad0019b0        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
25e18684046a        host                host                local
29da4987a368        none                null                local
```

and no other containers:

```
$ docker container ls -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

The traefik container comes up fine:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "testproject_webgateway" with driver "bridge"
Creating testproject_proxy_1 ... done
```

The `emilevauge/whoami` container has a small network issue:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
ERROR: Network traefik_webgateway declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create traefik_webgateway` and try again.
```

So I manually create it:

```
$ docker network create traefik_webgateway
2ee51f3bbd603984a056da6269775d50ab5549fe85c3caf457f4933bf0e97ffe
```

and rerun:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating test_whoami_1 ... done
```

At this point I am able to access the Traefik web UI and see the single whoami container:

[image: traefik web ui with single whoami container]

Finally I attempt to run the curl command, but receive a gateway timeout error:

```
$ curl -H Host:whoami.docker.localhost http://127.0.0.1
Gateway Timeout
```

The traefik container logs show this for the above:

```
time="2018-02-10T23:38:47Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: begin ServeHttp on request" Request="{"Method":"GET","URL":{"Scheme":"","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":"","Path":"/","RawPath":"","ForceQuery":false,"RawQuery":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Accept":["*/*"],"User-Agent":["curl/7.50.3"]},"ContentLength":0,"TransferEncoding":null,"Host":"whoami.docker.localhost","Form":null,"PostForm":null,"MultipartForm":null,"Trailer":null,"RemoteAddr":"172.18.0.1:55380","RequestURI":"/","TLS":null}"
time="2018-02-10T23:38:47Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/roundrobin/rr: Forwarding this request to URL" Request="{"Method":"GET","URL":{"Scheme":"","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":"","Path":"/","RawPath":"","ForceQuery":false,"RawQuery":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Accept":["*/*"],"User-Agent":["curl/7.50.3"]},"ContentLength":0,"TransferEncoding":null,"Host":"whoami.docker.localhost","Form":null,"PostForm":null,"MultipartForm":null,"Trailer":null,"RemoteAddr":"172.18.0.1:55380","RequestURI":"/","TLS":null}" ForwardURL=http://172.20.0.2:80
time="2018-02-10T23:38:47Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/forward: begin ServeHttp on request" Request="{"Method":"GET","URL":{"Scheme":"http","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":"172.20.0.2:80","Path":"","RawPath":"","ForceQuery":false,"RawQuery":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Accept":["*/*"],"User-Agent":["curl/7.50.3"]},"ContentLength":0,"TransferEncoding":null,"Host":"whoami.docker.localhost","Form":null,"PostForm":null,"MultipartForm":null,"Trailer":null,"RemoteAddr":"172.18.0.1:55380","RequestURI":"/","TLS":null}"
time="2018-02-10T23:38:47Z" level=debug msg="vulcand/oxy/forward/http: begin ServeHttp on request" Request="{"Method":"GET","URL":{"Scheme":"http","Opaque":"","User":null,"Host":"172.20.0.2:80","Path":"","RawPath":"","ForceQuery":false,"RawQuery":"","Fragment":""},"Proto":"HTTP/1.1","ProtoMajor":1,"ProtoMinor":1,"Header":{"Accept":["*/*"],"User-Agent":["curl/7.50.3"]},"ContentLength":0,"TransferEncoding":null,"Host":"whoami.docker.localhost","Form":null,"PostForm":null,"MultipartForm":null,"Trailer":null,"RemoteAddr":"172.18.0.1:55380","RequestURI":"/","TLS":null}"
```

I'm unsure if I am supposed to do anything else here.

I don't have a concrete answer, but upgrading to macOS 10.13.x fixed the issue.

Comment: i dont understand the question here

Answer (score 1):

I had also issue on using Traefik on my personal macbook compared to my workstation on my office that's running on Ubuntu...

Here's my reference...
https://docs.traefik.io/#test-it

First you want to use the docker way of using Traefik
[start docker compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ga6W.png)
Get the default network that's also listed on the terminal.
Second on your project's docker compose file add this on your yml file.
[docker-compose.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3QLM.png)

One more thing, please don't forget to add your desired domain on your `/etc/hosts/` file.
[my sample /etc/hosts file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx0Mt.png)

Hopefully, it would help!

Comment: Hello iamgerwin, 
Why do we need to add our desired domain to our /etc/hosts file? I was expecting that the mapping was done automatically by Traefik. I'm kind of new in the Mac world, but if I remember correctly in Windows I didn't need to add anything to my hosts file to be able to access the sites managed by Traefik.